# Does Material guidelines say anything about text color in warning modals?

Tags: color, guidelines

Does Material guidelines say anything about text color in warning modals?

I was told by my project manager to put the text inside a warning modal in red, but I think it looks ugly. I tried to find something about it on the Material guideline, but couldn't find anything. What color is it recommended to put as font color inside a warning modal and how do I tell the user this is particularly important without changing the font color?

https://material.io/design/color/text-legibility.html

It doesn't say that it's wrong, and so I am not sure if it's ok and what might be better.

Comment: It depends on the space occupied by the text and the design of the modal, any mockup?

Comment: Is it a modal or a warning dialog? In the first case, you can include whatever you want, there are no guidelines relating to color in modals other than the generic ones. If it's a warning alert, you can use red. Either way, remember Material is just a set of guidelines, it's not like you have to follow them to the A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Colored background, black text** is what is commonly used across multiple design systems for warning dialogs, and thus would be understandable by users. Depending on severity, yellow, orange, or pink/red are the background colors commonly used.

[image: Warning dialogs example 1]

[image: Warning dialogs example 2]

The problem with using red text for all warnings is that it's used for error states. That's a different case from a warning, which might not always be caused by a user error.

[image: Error message example in red]